# Populating View in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm trying to do is figure out how to pass in variables to a view from a controller.

For example, let's say I have a login screen where I want to display the application version and the some other custom device information. How would I go about passing that info into the view?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'loginform',
    config: {
        items: [
             { 
                 xtype: 'label', 
                 cls: 'appVersion', 
                 html: 'Version #:' + versionNumber 
             }
        ]
    }
});
```

Also how much different would it be if I used tpl instead of html ?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always pass data during view creation like this:

```
var loginPanel = Ext.create('MyApp.view.Login', {
    ver : versionNumber    // any value or data you want to pass
});
```

for that you might have to define `ver` in your view's config

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Login', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
  xtype: 'loginform',
  config: {
    ver : '',  // Initialize with empty string
    items: [
         { 
             xtype: 'label', 
             cls: 'appVersion', 
             html: 'Version #:' + versionNumber 
         }
    ]
  }
});
```

Once created with required value you can add it anywhere you want

```
Ext.Viewport.add(loginPanel);
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. Is there any other way to pass data / variables to the view from the controller?

For instance what if you built some complex dashboard. You have a controller with multiple views and some nested views. Let's say you are monitoring data from an external source or data that changes without user interaction.

How would I reflect those changes to my view? 

With a model any update would trigger a "change" event. You can use the change event to update the view. With a controller monitoring something external, how to update the view? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure whether you monitoring is pull or push, but in any case you have to write code in callback functions to pass variables to any view. Passing a variable alone won't help view if its already loaded, so passing data to store makes more sense if it refreshes periodically. Anyways to pass data you should be able to do something like this in controller `getLoginView().config.ver = newVersion`. Since this is not tested to I recommend you to do some trial and error in console.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use PhoneGap (Cordova) for this: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device

Also, using html or tpl is fine.

Comment: Thanks. I guess what I'm trying to ask is how to pass data from a controller to a view in Sencha Touch 2. I want to keep my view "dumb". So for instance in the controller use Cordova to gather whatever info and then pass that info from the controller into the view. In this example I'm saying application version but I mean data in general.